# How to put a text (span) below the image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn CSS and HTML and have a very basic question here. How do i write my css so that it shows the text in the span below the image

```
<div class="section">
    <ul>
        <li id="lumia820" class="figures" >
            <img src="f-lumia820.jpg" alt="" class="figure"/>
            <span class="figcaption">Lumia 820</span>
        </li>
        <li id="iphone4s" class="figures">
            <img src="f-iphone4s.jpg" alt="" class="figure"/>
            <span class="figcaption">Iphone 4s</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Currently, I have something like

```
.section ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

.figures {
    display: inline;
}

.figures span {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Palatino Linotype", Georgia, serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.figures img{
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 1% 1%;
}
```

Comment: plz you can check the updated one

Answer (score 3):

Just set the to `display: block;` so that each one takes up its own line. Right now, they are set to `display: inline` because that is the default for both `<img>` tags and `<span>` tags.

```
.figures span, .figures img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: beat me to it by 2 seconds :D

Comment: `.figures > *` is even shorter.

Comment: it works but it breaks something else. i mean now the text is shown below the image. but every thing is in one column. while i want two columns, one for each [image,text] category where text would be below image.

Comment: @LivingThing Easiest way for that is to change `.figures` to `float: left;` and have a clearfix after it. Another way would be to make `.figures` `display: inline-block;` and give them a width value.

Comment: the float left and the clear fix didnt work. I dont want to give a fixed width value as according to my limited understanding thats not a good idea for responsive web design.

Comment: thank you ktash, it seems what you are saying is right and it perfectly works in jsfiddle but for some reason not for me. I have removed everything from my css and just kept the stuff for figures class but it does not work still

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Answer (score 1):

should be able to do

```
.figcaption {
   display:block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52PEN/)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
.figures span{ display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/h6McP/1/

Span  and image is actually an inline element, so it wil come line by line
 we need to make to block element so that span will come exat below of the image

here i have given

`.figures  span {display:block}`

```
li.figures { display: inline-block;}
```

Check this is Updated one

Comment: sorry i am adding it now

Comment: it works but it breaks something else. i mean now the text is shown below the image. but every thing is in one column. while i want two columns, one for each [image,text] category where text would be below image